# Sync Mendeley library with Dropbox in both Mac and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, dropbox, synchronization, mendeley

I am using Mendeley in MacOS at work and in Ubuntu at home, and would like to sync my library with a Dropbox folder in both machines. I know it's possible to sync it with Dropbox, but only among computers with the same OS. Does anybody know how to do it among different OS?

Thanks

Comment: Dropbox does support syncing across different operating systems, and supports both Mac and Linux: https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=mac and https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Answer (score 0):

DropBox is not supported with Mendeley because Mendeley expects the files stored in it to remain unchanged, but DropBox changes files stored in it regularly. We advise against using DropBox with Mendeley for this reason.